# High pitch whine followed by static - laptop battery

Tags: laptop, battery, shutdown, noise, issue-tracking

Good Day guys,

Please can you assist. 
I was reinstalling windows on my girlfriend's laptop when a strange bussing came from the battery and the pc shut down. 
After multiple attempts to install windows 10, then 8, then 7...
After a day and a half of trial and only error, I realized that as soon as this noise starts, the battery stops charging and ultimately shuts the pc down. 
I removed the battery and plugged the cable in, windows is now installed and the pc is running perfectly after 8 hours.. 
Software is installed and all is running smoothly.

If I reinsert the battery it will charge and run fine for 10-15 min, then starts making a noise and shuts down.
Could this be an issue with the battery or something to do with a hidden setting somewhere?
If it is an issue with the battery, why would the pc not stay on using the power cable if the pc works fine without the battery and only using the cable?

The laptop in question is a Gigabyte M1022c, battery is a GNF-660 (GND-240)

Comment: As a Precaution: Stop using the battery, remove it and store in a place where if it explodes in a fireball (yes they can) it will not hurt anything, replace the battery Now!

Answer (score 1):

The whine is probably your battery charging circuitry working hard.

Either that circuitry is dead or dying or your battery is faulty and drawing far too much current.

It could be that there is a short somewhere in the battery pack which is only present when it gets warm during charging. It causes a drop in the voltage and causes your machine to brown out.

Internally inside batteries, particularly Li-Ion whiskers can form over time and cause these kinds of problems.

Without the battery there the short is not present and the system operates normally.

Otherwise it could be that the charging circuit is faulty and is overheating during operation and essentially disconnecting the battery while it is in use by the system. A sudden change in power source or specifications can cause a system to shutdown for safety. This would be preferred in the presence of batteries as sudden changes can indicate dangerous battery faults and drawing current from a faulty battery can lead to serious problems.

Replace the battery first as it is more likely at fault. If the problem persists then you may need to take your laptop to a specialist for repair.